# What exception is thrown without vpn?

Tags: android, vpn

Firstly, I am still very new to all this. Keep that in mind.
From my app I am connecting to a webservice which requires VPN connection. Is there any specific exception thrown when device is not connected to VPN? 
Also, is it possible to configure PPTP vpn programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to configure PPTP vpn profile programmatically. You have to configure it from settings.